# How to deploy python flask application on another windows 10?

Tags: python, flask, server

I have develop python flask application(REST API). Now I want to deploy this application on client system(Windows 10 Professional ). My client dont have any internet service.

Previously, I done in java that time I make a .war file and deployed in tomcat on client system. He was able to access REST API.

Now I want know any similar way to deploy python app on client system, on start system his able to access my REST API

Comment: see [Full Stack Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/table-of-contents.html). Is It Windows Server or Windows Home/Professional version (on desktop/notebook computer) ?

Comment: @furas windows 10 professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use PyInstaller.

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

go to project dir

```
cd C:\Users\sandip\Desktop\MyPython
```

use

```
pyinstaller --onefile HelloFlask.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make your rest APIs accessible by other users in same network, you can simply do it without installing anything on client side by replacing the `app.run()` in your code to `app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')`. By default flask app runs on localhost, by changing it to latter causes it to run on your machines IP address, thus making it accessible by all the users under same network. You can read more on [flask's documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) under the heading **Externally Visible Server**.

To deploy your app in production, you need a WSGI server, you can read about deployment of flask app [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/deploying/)

Comment: that I know , my question is on startup windows it shout automatic start the python file

Comment: You can write a shell script running your python application and add it in windows startup services. That way it will make sure even if computer restarts, the app keeps on running

Comment: the problem is here code is visible to package, Is any solution like java .war file

Comment: Not as such as python code is in form of scripts and not like conventional java or cpp code. It will always be visible and cannot be packaged.

Comment: OK that part. Please help me to run my API from .whl file. Can I run my application from .whl file. on windows startup

Comment: No, you cannot run whl package directly. You have to install the package and then import it in some python file. Only this way you can use your whl file